# Rails 4 nested resources Creating new records undefined method create_association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-resources

> undefined method `create_school' for #< User:0xb4e407a0 >

This is my create action

```
@school = current_user.create_school(school_params)
```

In my model definitions

`user has_one profile`
`profile has_many schools`

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between a `user` and a `school`.

If a `user` has many `schools` then you create an instance of the association by using

```
 current_user.schools.create(school_params)
```

If a `user` has one `school` then you use `create_association`

```
 current_user.create_school(school_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule-of-thumb, whenever you run associative methods on your models (typically `build` or `create`), the name of the method depends on the plurality of the association... plural associations need `association.create`, singular associations need `create_association`:

[`belongs_to` ref](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to) (specifically about [`create_`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to-create-association-attributes)):

> When you declare a belongs_to association, the declaring class
>   automatically gains five methods related to the association:
>
> - association(force_reload = false)
> - association=(associate)
> - build_association(attributes = {})
> - create_association(attributes = {})
> - create_association!(attributes = {})

--

[`has_many` ref](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) (specifically about [`.create`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-create-attributes)):

> When you declare a has_many association, the declaring class
>   automatically gains 16 methods related to the association:
>
> - collection(force_reload = false)
> - ...
> - collection.build({})
> - collection.create(attributes = {})
> - collection.create!(attributes = {})

---

Thus, if you're using a `has_many` association, you'll need to use `x.create`:

```
@school = current_user.schools.create school_params
```